# Hexa-decimal value to String in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

> 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

This is hexa-decimal value i have, i couldn't able to it string, its not like ordinary converstion i need help!
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: But why? What kind of data does the hex-string contain?

Comment: It is unicode text and means something like "ýý T a b l e I d   Ôÿ  ÿý R e c I d   1~ð P   ÿý P a r t i t i o n   1   P   ÿý r e c V e r s i o n      ÿý s e q u e n c e N u m   1~ð P   ÿý d a t a A r e a I d    d a t   ÿý c r e a t e d B y    d b a l a c h a   ÿý d E L _ C r e "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use convert like this:

```
declare @hex varbinary(max) = 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
declare @string nvarchar(max)

set @string = Convert(nvarchar(MAX), @hex, 1)
select @hex, @string
```

Comment: But the "1" at the end will not bring back the string and this seems to be what the OP wants...

Comment: I am not following you???

Comment: Well, I tried it out (set query output to text): select CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @hex,1) comes back with "0x07FD0707FD0054 ...." and select CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @hex) comes back with "ýý T a b l e I d   Ôÿ  ÿý R e c I d ...." . (encoding issue)

Comment: '0x07FD0707FD0054...' is a string ? hence the 1. otherwise you get 'ﴇ܇ýTableId'

Comment: Well, the result of "ýý T a b l e I d   Ôÿ  ÿý R e c I d..." is not per incidence :-) It is a unicode string passed in a "raw" format.

Comment: http://abraaxapta.blogspot.com/2011/06/accessing-dynamics-ax-containers-from.html

From the above link, i had found to get data from the container, it is not working fine larger data